# The code is deleting the entire file instead of ammending the line I want in Java

Tags: java, arrays, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have made a seatbooking system and need one of the options to cancel the seat. I have written this code which is similar to the code when booking a seat but at the moment it is deleting the entire file and I can't figure out why. PS I know the cancel operation needs more validation which I will input when I've figure out how to change the right thing. The correct validation will be and email address.

```
private static void cancelSeat() throws IOException {

    int index = 0;
    System.out.println("-- Please Enter Your Seat Number To Cancel Your Reservation --");
    String userSeat = input.next().toUpperCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
        seatBookingSystem current = seats[i];
        if (current.getSeatNumber().equals(userSeat)){
            seats[i].cancel();
            System.out.println("-- Your Reservation Has Now Been Canceled, Goodbye --");    
        }
    }
    //write the new string with the replaced line OVER the same file

    BufferedWriter amendFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\sylve\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\seats2.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
        amendFile.write(seats[i].ammendFile());
    }
    amendFile.close();

    System.out.print("-- Your Has Seat Been Canceled, Thank You! --");
}
```

two other parts of the code that gets called are cancel() and ammendFile()

```
public String cancel() {
    return this.email = "free";
}

public String ammendFile() {
    DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    String result = seatNumber + " " + seatClass +  " " + isWindow + " " + isAisle + " " + isTable + " " + dF.format(seatPrice) + " " + email + "\n";
    return result;
}
```

and the file I want to ammend where the booking is held.

```
1A STD true false false 23.50 free
1B STD false true false 23.50 free
1D STD true true false 27.50 free
2A STD true false true 24.50 free
2B STD false true true 24.50 free
2D STD true true true 28.50 BOB
3A STD true false true 24.50 free
3B STD false true true 24.50 free
3D STD true true true 28.50 free
4A STD true false false 23.50 free
4B STD false true false 23.50 free
4D STD true true false 27.50 free
5A 1ST true true true 48.50 free
5C 1ST false true true 44.50 free
5D 1ST true false true 44.50 free
6A 1ST true true true 48.50 free
6C 1ST false true true 44.50 free
6D 1ST true false true 44.50 free
```

Comment: Note that once your FileWriter is fixed as per @AustinAdams' answer, you'll be appending the amendment to the end of the file instead of overwriting the line that already exists for that seat. Is that what you want? If not, you're going to also have to read the file first to find the line you need to modify.

Comment: No its not what I want, what I want to do is amend the array first to store the new data and then print that back to the file, so I don't have to keep reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating your FileWriter with append mode on.  you need to change this line:

```
BufferedWriter amendFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\sylve\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\seats2.txt"));
```

to this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\sylve\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\seats2.txt", true);
BufferedWriter amendFile = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```